# How do you use regular expressions to check if a String in Java ends with at least one digit?

Tags: java, regex

I try to use the regex to check the username should start with letters and ends with at least one digit, but the following code only allows me to end with 1 digit, and I'm not sure about whether I used the * correctly, I think "[regex]*" means match at least one times [regex]

```
if( username.matches("^[a-zA-z]*\\d*$") ){
System.out.println("The username is valid");

}
else{
System.out.println("The username is invalid");

}
```

Comment: [Here's a cool tool for regex.](http://regex101.com)

Comment: * matches 0 or more, + matches 1 or more

Comment: [Also, your code works fine for me for more than 1 digit.](https://ideone.com/ONuI36)

Comment: As listed at the bottom of the [StackOverflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Non-stackoverflow references: Tools (testers and explainers) > Online testers", there are many online resources where you can try things out yourself.

Comment: @morgano, thanks, I would try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close:

```
^[a-zA-z]+[\d]+$
```

`^[a-zA-z]+` make sure there is at least one character at the beginning of the string.

`[\d]+$` make sure there is at least one digit at the end.